# How to change id on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, canvas

I have a page that displays a gif icon based on a string on a canvas. For example "clear-day". It is possible to fetch that string from an api. My question is how i assign the variable "icon" that includes that string to the id of my canvas. Of course there are better ways of doing this as i´m a beginner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Animated weather icons</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<figure class="icons">
    <canvas class="weatherIcon" width="64" height="64"></canvas>
</figure>

<script src="https://rawgithub.com/darkskyapp/skycons/master/skycons.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function weather(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/59.868098,%2017.678976?lang=sv&callback=?",
function(json) {
var weatherJSON = json.currently;
var icon=weatherJSON.icon;

    var icons = new Skycons({"color": "white"});

icons.set("clear-day", Skycons.CLEAR_DAY);
icons.set("clear-night", Skycons.CLEAR_NIGHT);
icons.set("partly-cloudy-day", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY);
icons.set("partly-cloudy-night", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT);
icons.set("cloudy", Skycons.CLOUDY);
icons.set("rain", Skycons.RAIN);
icons.set("sleet", Skycons.SLEET);
icons.set("snow", Skycons.SNOW);
icons.set("wind", Skycons.WIND);
icons.set("fog", Skycons.FOG);

var iconWeather = document.getElementsByClassName("weatherIcon");
iconWeather.id = icon;


icons.play();

});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have to clarify what you want. "assign the variable "icon" that includes that string to the id of my canvas" Do you want to set the canvas element's `id` to the object's property `icon.id`? or set `canvas.id` to the object `icon`? (which can not be done as `id` can only hold strings) Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].setAttribute("id", icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

Document.getElementByClassName returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Change iconWeather.id = icon; to iconWeather[0].setAttribute("id", icon);

Comment: Created codepen URL for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ybJPpy